# MySQL Double The Amount Of Data In Database With No Orphaned Data

Tags: python, mysql, database

For testing purposes I would like to double the amount of data in the database.

Is there a better methodological way of going about this besides looping through the table schema like:

`select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='<database_name>';`

For table_name in result:

`explain <database_name>.<table_name>;`

Create objects in python based on table

`select * from <table_name>;`

Stuff that data into the objects we created

Change objects primary key (GUID) to a new guid and if that primary key exists anywhere else in other objects change that to the same guid

Insert new data into database.

Expected Outcome:
This would double the amount of objects I have in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create objects in Python.  You can re-insert the data from a table into itself:

```
insert into t
    select t.*
    from t;
```

This assumes that no columns are identity columns (probably a bad assumption).  So, you need to list the columns:

```
insert into t(col1, col2, . . .)
    select col1, col2, . . .
    from t;
```

Don't include the identity column.  Let it get its default value.  If the identity is not set, then you might need to do something like:

```
insert into t(col1, col2, . . .)
    select t.id + maxid + 1, col1, col2, . . .
    from t cross join
         (select max(id) as maxid from t) m;
```

For a UUID, you would generate a new key using a function.

But, there is no need to move the data outside the database for this operation.

Comment: This also assumes that the foreign key relationships were set up correctly in the database right? I'm not sure that, that is always the case

Comment: OP just wants to double the data in the database, so I feel like just making a copy of a table to a new table would mitigate the identity problem

Comment: @cricket_007 . . . Nothing in this answer suggests creating a new table.  The queries just re-insert the table's data back into the same table.

Comment: I know, and that might work, but I was simply suggesting something like "insert into table2 select * from table1" would also double the size of the database

Comment: @cricket_007 . . . That is the first suggestion in this answer.